# TFS - Git - permissions

Tags: git

I have a master branch and a dev branch.  How can I share the dev branch only.  Or do I need to share the master and limit people from making changes.  This might seem easy but I haven't found any documentation that describes this.

The developers that are going to be working on the dev branch have just been hired remotely and I want to make sure my master branch is safe.

Thanks